# Dynamic Text based on pages in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a sidebar and toolbar that over each of my different pages (home, about etc.). I want the top toolbar to have text that reflects what page you are on but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried implementing an ngIf alongside routerLink to check if the routerLink is pointed to the home page but it doesn't work and I'm not sure what else to do.

```
    <mat-toolbar >
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span *ngIf = "[routerLink]"="[/']">Home</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <ng-content></ng-content>


  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

Comment: you are having this toolbar code in different component?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to router event in your component and then compare activeRoute:

```
activeRoute: string;
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url) {
        this.activeRoute = event.url;
      }
    });
}
```

now in your html you can compare it:

```
<mat-toolbar >
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span *ngIf="activeRoute=='/'">Home</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide some data in routing:

```
{
    path: `main`,
    component: MainComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Main page'
    }
},
```

And inside component you can catch this data:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.snapshot.data['title'];
  }
}
```

After that you can save title in service/store/component property and provide as input params where you need.

Answer (score 0):

We can make header as Component and then pass your header text as [**`@Input`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) to that.

This also helps to make some of the other benefits like maintaining *routing history*, *dynamic styling* and other benefits.

You can find more details here, [*creating-app-header-component*](https://medium.com/developing-an-angular-4-web-app/creating-app-header-component-242a6e5b555)

Hope this helps.. :)